# How to delay change after the transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a transition animation, but I can't figure out how to delay the change, in that case it's the rounded-full till the end of the hover animation.

What I'm trying to achieve is that the rounded-full will kick in AFTER the scale-110 animation, but as you can see, the rounded-full is kicking in as soon as I hover the button.

I appreciate any help with achieving that.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/TqEiR65nDB

Code:

```
<div class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
  <button class="transition duration-1000 ease-in-out bg-blue-600 hover:bg-red-600 hover:rounded-full transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110">
    Hover me
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

After the `transition` attribute you can add a `delay` attribute followed by a number `delay-75` for example